# why can't able to get values in proper manner for char[][] using fgets in for loop

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
     char str[10][50];
     for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
         fgets(str[i],50,stdin);//some runtime error occurs and execution stops completely
     for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
         printf("str[%d]=%s\n",i,str[i]);
     return 0;
}
```

I want to give input as `str[0]="hello world"` and `str[1]="good answer"` till `str[9]` but i am not able to give inputs using below `for()` loop

Comment: Is the code you show the actual code that causes the problem? Is it an actual [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that exhibits the problem? If not, can you please create an MCVE to show us? I wonder because [I can't replicate your problem](http://ideone.com/YGwkwM).

Comment: How many inputs are you able to give?

Comment: I doubt this is the code that causes a runtime error.

Comment: @4386427 yes exactly this code doesn't causes any run-time error, only compile time error, in c. for declaring c inside `for()` loop

Comment: Did you enter 10 lines of input or less?  Post all 10  lines of input.

Comment: "can't able to get values" and code not checking the return value of `fgets()` is weak coding.  Only use `str[i]` if  `fgets(str[i],50,stdin)` returned non-`NULL`.

Answer (score -2):

Well you are doing dynamic declaration in c program inside `for()` loop which is not allowed in C programming language but it is allowed in C++.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
     char str[10][50];
     int i;
     for(i=0;i<10;i++)
         fgets(str[i],50,stdin); 
     for(i=0;i<10;i++)
         printf("str[%d]=%s\n",i,str[i]);
     system("pause");
     return 0;
}
```

this program works just fine.

Comment: Declaring iterator variables like the OP does has been in the language since the C99 standard. And if that was the problem it would lead to a compiler error not a crash at run-time.

Comment: I understand that and this program  is giving compile time error only not run time error,array is defined used and printed properly, no chance of run time error

Comment: From the code shown: "//some **runtime error occurs** and execution stops completely"

Comment: yes i ran into my system it is running ok. after removing compile time error

Comment: havent been on Visual C for long time, but maybe its jsut microsoft nto supporting it? Be aware that MSVS C is different from plain C as the C standards describe it